# matrix normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that any $2\times2$ complex matrix is similar to a unique matrix of the form:$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\\theta_1 & \theta_2\end{bmatrix}$$

$\theta_i$ are complex.

I tried to use schur decomposition but it is not of this form and not unique.

thank you

Comment: Can you show that any $2\times 2$ matrix in JNF is similar to exactly one such?

Comment: JNF is not unique

Comment: Jordan normal form. The usual normal form of similarity classes. It _is_ unique up to rearrangement of the blocks. You can define an order to make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is
$$\det(\lambda I - A)  = \lambda^2 + \theta_2 \lambda + \theta_1$$
Since similarity transforms leave the characteristic polynomial alone, the matrix is unique. It remains to be shown that a $2\times 2$ matrix with this characteristic polynomial is indeed similar to $A$.

For this we use the JNF. A $2\times 2$ matrix can have one of two (ordered) JNFs with $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \in\mathbb C$ $\circledast$ it's eigenvalues; not necessarily distinct:

$$\begin{align*}
& M \sim \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix} \\
\text{or } & M \sim \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&1\\0&\lambda_1\end{bmatrix} & \text{where }\lambda_1=\lambda_2
\end{align*}$$

In the former case, $\theta_1 = \lambda_1\lambda_2$ and $\theta_2 = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$, and in the latter case $\theta_1 = \lambda_1^2$ and $\theta_2=0$. I'll leave it to you to find the respective transform matrices.

$\circledast$: You can chose any ordering here. If you don't want that, you can expand the first case into two cases linked by the additional transform $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\big)$.

Comment: thank you I will try form here

Comment: How are you proposing to well-order $\mathbb{C}$ to order your eigenvalues?

Comment: @Chappers This entirely irrelevant to the proof. Only the _existence_ of _some_ order is required. For example take the lexicograpic product of the absolute value ordering with the argument ordering (i.e. $z\le w \Leftrightarrow |z|<|w| \vee (|z|=|w| \wedge \mathrm{arg}(z) \le \mathrm{arg}(w))$.